# in PHP 5.3.3 how can a "per server" or "per instance" or "per website" variable be defined and used?

Tags: php, variables, scope, instance, apc

for what I've tried "static" variables and apc_add or apc_store are "per session", and I'm looking for a "sitewide" variable in memory.  Of course it can be handled in a database or in a file, but if possible I'd like to avoid those options.

Comment: Welp, my only suggestion given the possibilities you outlined above is to use `auto_prepend_file` and in that file, use constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sitewide variables, I have done a few things.

1. Use apache environment variables in httpd.conf
2. Use memcachedand the PHP memcache libraries

Comment: thanks for your fast response, you pointed me in the right direction.  In case it helps someone else, for installing the memcached server on centos 6 I used: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-memcached-on-centos-6/